# create Class in Qt with QDialog inside for specific Dialogs

Tags: c++, qt

I just want to make a custom Dialog, so I want to make a class around the standard QDialog. The goal is to call the constructor which creates the Dialog, and the show() function should be called to make it shown. Next step would be to make a connect between my Widget (which calls the Dialog constructor) Pushbutton and the show() function.

My header looks like this:

```
#include <QDialog>

class Dialog_Setting : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Dialog_Setting();

  public slots:
    void show(void);

  private:
    QDialog * dialog;
};
```

my .cpp:

```
   #include "Dialog_Setting.h"

Dialog_Setting::Dialog_Setting()
{
  dialog = new QDialog;
}

void Dialog_Setting::show()
{
  dialog->show();
}
```

I have taken out my connect and get a new error. 
What is wrong with my class?

> undefined reference to `vtable for Dialog_Setting'

thanks for your help, I love StackOverflow

Comment: Show complete class of `Dialog_Setting`.

Comment: Working in Qt creator? If so, run Qmake

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `show()` is implemented as a **slot** so you can `connect()` stuff to it:

```
#include <QDialog>

class Dialog_Setting : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Dialog_Setting();

public slots:
    void show();
};
```

You also forgot to inherit from `QObject` or some other *QObject-based* class like `QDialog` and to declare the macro Q_OBJECT. All of these things are required to make your custom classes communicate with other classes through `connect()`.

Comment: but in the new Qt Syntax we don't need slots anymore, public functions do it  also..?
I tried it, does not solve the problem..

Comment: @TomoBogdanovic Updated answer. Take your time to notice every little detail in my code.

Comment: I changed it now, and I took out the connect, the problem seems to be somewhere else

Comment: Why did you remove the `connect()`? Also, you talked about a technical problem but you didn't say what exactly it is that your program is supposed to do. Edit your question and tell us what are you trying to do.